# GitLab Pipleine Error: Bad Request when sending attachment through SendGrid

Tags: gitlab, sendgrid, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to send an email notification using SendGrid task in my GitLab Pipeline.

Whenever I am sending an empty attachment it is going fine, but when I'm trying to attach my `checkov` report converted to base64.
It is showing bad request error.

The pipeline:

```yaml
send_email:
  image: alpine
  stage: send_email
  before_script:
    - apk add curl file
  script:
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH="reports/checkov.txt"
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILENAME=$(basename $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH)
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_BASE64_CONTENT=$(base64 -i $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH)
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILETYPE=$(file -b --mime-type $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH)
    - echo $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILENAME
    - echo $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILETYPE
    - echo $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_BASE64_CONTENT
    - |
      curl --request POST \
      --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
      --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --data "{
        \"personalizations\": [{\"to\": [{\"email\": \"RECIPIENT_EMAIL\"}], \"subject\": \"Your job report is here!\"}],
        \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"See the attached job report.\"}],
        \"from\": {\"email\": \"SENDER_EMAIL\", \"name\": \"Your GitLab\"},
        \"attachments\": [{
          \"content\": \"$SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_BASE64_CONTENT\",
          \"type\": \"$SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILETYPE\",
          \"filename\": \"$SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILENAME\"
        }]
      }"
```

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try, instead of embedding the base64 encoded content directly in the JSON payload, to create a JSON file with the email content and pass it to the `curl` command.
This should help avoid any potential issues with character escaping and line breaks.

```yaml
send_email:
  image: alpine
  stage: send_email
  before_script:
    - apk add curl file jq
  script:
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH="reports/checkov.txt"
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILENAME=$(basename $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH)
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_BASE64_CONTENT=$(base64 -i $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH)
    - SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILETYPE=$(file -b --mime-type $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILE_PATH)
    - echo $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILENAME
    - echo $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILETYPE
    - echo $SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_BASE64_CONTENT
    - |
      EMAIL_JSON=$(jq -n \
        --arg sg_content "$SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_BASE64_CONTENT" \
        --arg sg_type "$SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILETYPE" \
        --arg sg_filename "$SENDGRID_ATTACHMENT_FILENAME" \
        '{
          "personalizations": [{ "to": [{ "email": "RECIPIENT_EMAIL" }], "subject": "Your job report is here!" }],
          "content": [{ "type": "text/plain", "value": "See the attached job report." }],
          "from": { "email": "SENDER_EMAIL", "name": "Your GitLab" },
          "attachments": [{
            "content": $sg_content,
            "type": $sg_type,
            "filename": $sg_filename
          }]
        }'
      )
      echo $EMAIL_JSON
      curl --request POST \
        --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data "$EMAIL_JSON"
```